# How to implement lazy loading of image without using SDImageCache?

Tags: objective-c

How to implement lazy loading  of image without using below link:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Note: I don't want to use any third party tool. I want to do from my side.

Comment: than use https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache

Comment: check out this link:[https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/)

Comment: I want use without using any third party tool ,Thanks Ronak

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any library (some are MIT or public domain licensed, so I think the only reason not to use them is that you want to learn how to build it yourself).

Here is how to do it with a simple and effective way:

**1 :** Put a temporary placeholder image in your imageView.

**2 :** Get your image in background thread.

*2-a* : If you want the cache feature, search for a cached image.

*2-b :* If no cache feature or no cached image, get your image from its source.

*2-c :* If cache feature, save the image to cache.

**3 :** In main thread show your image in the imageView.

**Pseudo Code** : (I wrote it on the go, it is not meant to run and it may have errors, sorry for that).

```
-(void) lazilyLoadImageFromURL :(NSURL *)url{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png];


if([self cachedImageAvailableForURL:url){

imageView.image= [self cachedImageForURL:url];

}
else{

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * resp, NSData     *data, NSError *error) 
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ 
                   {
                        if ( error == nil && data )
                        {
                            UIImage *urlImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                            imageView.image = urlImage;
                            [self saveImageInCache:image forURL:url];
                            }
                       });
    }];
}

}

-(BOOL) cachedImageAvailableForURL:(NSURL*):url{
        // check if there is a saved cached image for this url
 }
-(UIImage *) cachedImageForURL:(NSURL*):url{
        // returns the cached image for that url
}
-(void) saveImageInCache:(UIImage*) image forURL:(NSURL*)url{
        // saves the image in cache for the url
}
```

Of course, this is only ONE POSSIBLE WAY to do it. I tried to make it simple, but there are plenty better and more complicated ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
       NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www...."];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update the UI
                    self.imgVWprofile.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                });
            });
```